# How to find the client that is pushing a Git Tag

Tags: git, bitbucket

Does git keep a record of who pushed a tag? We are trying to delete some old tags but they keep getting pushed back to the remote. Is this information contained in the tag or do I need to look at the logs of the server?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not contained in the tag. Only the information of the person who created the tag is available. You need to look at the server logs to find out who pushed it.

Answer (score 0):

See the [git book for info on tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging).

If the tag was annotated, `git show tag_name`

Otherwise, server logs may have something, but your next best option is to narrow down **when** the tag reappears and find out who pushed to the remote. Maybe even start a scheduled task/cron job that does a `git fetch` and then `git tag -l "some_search_string*"` list tags to find the offending items. This can narrow down the time (and users) pushing the tags up.